# Convert ternary constraint into set of binary

Tags: constraint-satisfaction

I have the following ternary constraint that needs to be converted into a set of binary constraints in order to be used for a constraints solving problem:

```
A = max(b,c)+1
```

How can I do this?

I am allowed to introduce a new variable X to do this.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/166881/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/78090891/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score -1):

You can't.  You add the constraints `A <= b+1` and `A <= c+1` but there is no set of binary constraints that are equivalent to your original constraint.  This is true even if you're allowed to add additional variables.

Comment: @Stackbot124, please don't put additional information in the comments.  Please spend more time reflecting on what your actual question *is*, and then edit your question to ask the question you actually care about, and include all relevant context and requirements.  This is a site where we collaborate to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others.  So, that requires that the question be well-formulated and that it be useful to others.